# Flexbox and responsiveness: how to get items to wrap and then take up the full width of their new space without overflow?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I'm building an app that has some overlay panels over a video section. I'm trying to make this responsive and rather than having all the panels shrink, I want to just move them into the position shown in the **shrunken view** image below.

The panel in the top right is absolutely positioned and doesn't need to shrink/move at all when the screen size changes, the ones that need to change are the left side panel and the bottom red panel.

I made a quick **[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/xxjRarW)** for this.

I figured the best way to work with this is using `flex-direction: column` the wrap property to get this to work, however, if you do this you have some overflow from the red element if it's `width: 100%` (if you dont do this the red box will only be half the width of the space).

Like this:

[image]

So I figured I'd capture the width of the blue box and then calc the width so that it doesn't overflow. This *seems* like it works when you're in the **shrunken view**, but then you always have that calced value space on the **initial view**

like this:

[image]

So is there any way to make this look like the **Ideal Shrunken View**? What am I missing with the use of flexbox here? Is there a way to make this happen that I'm not considering?

**Initial View**

[image]

**Ideal Shrunken View**

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**Sass**

```
.wrapper
  --width-top-left: 20px
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  flex-wrap: wrap
  height: 60px
  // height: 50px
  
.top-left
  height: 30px
  width: var(--width-top-left)
  
.bottom
  height: 22px
  margin-top: auto
  width: calc(100% - var(--width-top-left))

----------------Box Styles-------------------------

.wrapper
  border: thin solid goldenrod
  position: relative
.bottom
  background: lightcoral
.top-left
  background: mediumslateblue
.top-right
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  right: 0
  background: mediumseagreen
  height: 20px
  width: 30px
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a media query to change flex-direction to row for the parent then changed the bottom bar to width:auto and flex-grow:1 so it stretches to fit the parent. Is that what you're looking for?

```css
.wrapper {
  --width-top-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
}

.top-left {
  height: 30px;
  width: var(--width-top-left);
}

.bottom {
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  border: thin solid goldenrod;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.top-left {
  background: mediumslateblue;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: mediumseagreen;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
}

.shrunkenview {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .top-left {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .bottom {
    width: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .initialview {
    display: none;
  }
  .shrunkenview {
    display: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"><span class='shrunkenview'>Shrunken View</span><span class='initialview'>InitialView</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! 
This works pretty well. I was hoping to avoid media queries and hoped that flexbox could carry me through

Comment: It might be possible. I'll have a think....

Comment: I appreciate it. I've been sitting with this pickle in my head for the better part of the day and it's killing meXD

Comment: After having an evening fiddling with this incluing doing weird stuff like setting the reading direction vertical-lr I'm still stumped! I'm not saying it's impossible as there's some CSS wizards about who can wrangle some pretty amazing things but I'm admitting defeat!

Comment: I appreciate it! It truly is a ticky situation, but I think your fix is good enough for me honestly. Thanks again for all the help!